# Get a variable value to a register with AsmJit

Tags: assembly, asmjit

How can I get a variable value to a register using AsmJit API? Some thing like below?

```
int x = 234;
Assember a;
a.mov(rax, $value_of_x);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AsmJit supports immediate operands, all you need is:

```
using namespace asmjit;

// Create and configure X86Assembler:
X86Assembler a(...);

// The answer:
int x = 234;
a.mov(x86::rax, x);
```

or just

```
a.mov(x86::rax, 234);
```

The previous examples used function overloads that accept immediate values directly. However, it's also possible to create the `Imm` operand and use it in your code dynamically:

```
Imm x = imm(234);
a.mov(x86::rax, x);
```

Or:

```
a.mov(x86::rax, imm(x));
```